# winrt, javascript, image from byte array

Tags: javascript, image, windows-8

I have a C++/CX component that can return an image as a stream (I could easily make it return an IBuffer, if that makes things easier). Currently, the component's return type is IRandomAccessStream and the actual stream is a InMemoryRandomAccessStream.

I want to use this stream as the source for an image in a HTML/JavaScript Windows 8 app. The problem is that I don't know how to shove this stream, or an array that I can create from it, into the image. I've tried a few things, but for example URL.createObjectURL deosn't take just an IRandomAccessStream, it requires an IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType. I've also tried to use a canvas and imagedata (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createimagedata.asp).

My next step will probably be to try to wrap my stream in a IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType and see if I can make that work. Either in JavaScript or in my C++/CX control.

Any suggestions on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in C# before not in C++, but the basics should be similar.

1. Get the byte array from the stream
2. Convert the byte array to Base64String ([Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1))
3. Now you can use this string directly in the image tag:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,YOUR_STRING" />`

Comment: Thanks, although I already managed to solve it by creating a RandomAccessStreamReference and then reading from it (as it returns the correct thing for use in URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: @Tomas I am having the same problem. It seams u have solve it. Would  you be so kind to share it with us?