# Javascript: loading image from bytearray

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, png, jpeg

In Javascript you have the ByteArray type and some views on it as described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

is it possible to store image data in such bytes and if yes, how can i display such an image? png or jpg?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463981/displaying-byte-array-as-image-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store an image using the typed arrays.

Im not sure what you want actually.
If you want to create an HTMLImageElement from a ByteArray, you can do something similar as cited in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162945/winrt-javascript-image-from-byte-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312939/convert-picturestream-to-html5-canvas).

If you want to get the bytes from an Image, that would be trickier. You can draw the ImageElement to HTML canvas, and them get the URI back using [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement).

I just tried to get the data using canvas and it worked.

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
    myCanvas.width = img.width;
    myCanvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
    alert(myCanvas.toDataURL());
};
img.src = "logo4w.png";
```

Although, the method toDataURL() do not allow you to perform this operation if the image you draw on canvas comes from outside the website domain.